# Different output calling javascript sort function twice

Tags: javascript, sorting, null

I'm facing with a sorting problem in javascript. I wrote a simple sorting function where I want the null elements on top:

This is the function:

```
var mySort = function(a, b) {
 if (!a && !b) return 0;
 if (!a) return -1;
 if (!b) return -1;
 if (a > b) return 1;
 if (a < b) return -1;
 return 0;
}
```

Let's take the following array as example:

```
var array = [1, 9, 4, 8, null, 2, 3, 4, null, 6, 3, 2, 8, 9, 5];
```

By calling `array.sort(mySort)` the non null values are always sorted, but the null values position alternate from the beginning and the end of the array:

```
Odd calls: [null, null, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9]
Even calls: [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9, null, null]
```

Why?

Edit:
In a comment HMR head me to an error in the algorithm: `if (!b) return -1;` should be `if (!b) return 1;`. Now it works fine with stings and numbers.

Comment: You can call it as many times as you want if you do: `array.slice().sort(mySort)` if one item is falsy (null) it's either put on the start or the end but if they're both null then none of the items are moved. So the nulls will group at the start or the end. If you do `if (!b) return 1;` then it'll also always be the same.

Comment: I don't really get the point of your answer. I already know about slicing the array, but IMHO it is a hack. I'd like to know why the null are switched even if the function is the same...it should be always the same result...

Comment: No it doesn't. sort mutates and you return -1 for cases where a is null and b is not or vice versa, this causes null's to either be at the start or at the end depending on the order sort will compare the items and where the items were to start with. You could either not mutate the array (use `slice`) or return a different value when one is null.

Comment: Damn.... `if (!b) return -1;` is wrong, it should be `if (!b) return 1;` Now it works fine!.Thanks!

Comment: do you have `null` or `'null'` as string in the array?

Comment: null without quotes

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the relation between two items. If both items are `null`, then change nothing, if you have one `null` value, then it depends on the position.

The best way is to check the items and get the delta of the check for sorting.

```js
function mySort(a, b) {
    return (b === null) - (a === null) || a - b;
}

var array = [1, 9, 4, 8, null, 2, 3, 4, null, 6, 3, 2, 8, 9, 5];

array.sort(mySort);
console.log(array);

array.sort(mySort);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I copied your example, it behavies as mine does. Try to call the sort a second time, the null values will go at the end.

Comment: it keeps the order. on which user agent is this running?

Comment: Chrome Version 70.0.3538.102

Comment: it is working fine with 70.0.3538.102 and the very actual version 70.0.3538.110 on windows.

Comment: Ok, but I need something that works on (almost) every browser.

Comment: it should do, becuase it separates `null` from not `null` values and sorts then. maybe you try to use a superfluous zero at the end, like `return (b === null) - (a === null) || a - b || 0;` which eliminates a possible NaN at the end.